# regular expression for updating FSF address

Tags: regex

I need to update the Free Software Foundation postal address from the old

```
59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
```

to the new

```
51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA
```

in the license statement of thousands of files. Sometimes, the address is line-broken, sometimes extra spaces are added, and the comment symbol may be different according to whatever language the file is written in, i.e., the string might appear as

```
//  59 Temple Place,
//  Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
```

or

```
#  59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston,
#  MA 02111-1307, USA
```

or

```
%  59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
```

Which script or regular expression can handle this?

Comment: Chances are you're going to have better luck doing this in Notepad++ or a similar editor for the replacement aspect.

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to give you some guidance, and you may still have to tweak it, this Regex should get you close:

```
^(59\s+Temple\s+Place.*02111-1307.*USA)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lIXN4Is0H2vLOryG)

But the replacement, keep in mind, would be single-line rather than multiline. Now, what application you use to do this; that's up to you.

The `.*` is used to match across multiple lines because I've turned that option on in the Regex engine. If it breaks across lines differently; you'll need to adjust it as such.